# Find double integrals boundaries.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I have to solve this integral

$$\iint_D xy {\,\rm d}x {\,\rm d}y$$

where the domain $D$ is delimited by: $x^2+y^2=4$ and $y^2=3x$;

My problem is that I don't know how should I plot those and more important how should i get my integration boundaries.
$$\int_?^?\int_?^? xy {\,\rm d}x {\,\rm d}y$$
I did the plot in wolfram alpha, but i still can't figure it out what my integrals boundaries are ([http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D4%2C+y%5E2%3D3x](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2by%5E2=4,%20y%5E2=3x))

Comment: You can check the answer you get with Wolfram Alpha by the query:  integrate x y Boole(x^2 + y^2 <= 4 && y^2 <= 3 x) for -3<=x<=3 and -3<=y<=3

Or use the corresponding command directly in *Mathematica*. (Of course you need to verify first that the entire region is inside that square.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a sketch of the region $D$ and you wil see that the integral is
$$
\iint_D\ldots {\,\rm d}x {\,\rm d}y
=
\int_{-\sqrt3}^\sqrt3\int_{y^2/3}^{\sqrt{4-y^2}} \ldots {\,\rm d}x {\,\rm d}y.
$$